# linker error when linking libcrypto.dylib

Tags: macos, openssl, libcrypto

macOS 10.14.3, Xcode 9.4.1:

I am trying to use `podofo` in my project. I get the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x62 0x6F 0x6F 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6D 0x61 0x72 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x62 0x6F 0x6F 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6D 0x61 0x72 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free", referenced from:
      PoDoFo::RC4CryptoEngine::~RC4CryptoEngine() in libpodofo.a(PdfEncrypt.o)
      PoDoFo::AESCryptoEngine::~AESCryptoEngine() in libpodofo.a(PdfEncrypt.o)
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new", referenced from:
      PoDoFo::RC4CryptoEngine::RC4CryptoEngine() in libpodofo.a(PdfEncrypt.o)
      PoDoFo::AESCryptoEngine::AESCryptoEngine() in libpodofo.a(PdfEncrypt.o)
```

What am I doing wrong? What does that mean?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0x62 0x6F 0x6F 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x6D 0x61 0x72 0x6B 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

To Ascii is `BOOK    MARK`    .

Is `/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib` here actually the library you want to link in the program?

Comment: '/usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib' is a soft link. The library is '/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1i/lib/libcrypto.lib'.

Comment: I copyed it to /usr/local/lib. Successed! Thank you very much.